# How to add a column in entity on Symfony 1.4 using line command?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have some problem. I work on symfony 1.4. I want to add a new column in my table and generate in php getter and setter to use it.

So In my shema.yml I add my column in my table like this:

```
version : {type: integer}
userName_canonical : {type: varchar(255)}
email_canonical : {type: varchar(255)}
qualifications: {type: array}
qualification_autre: {type: string}
promo: {type: boolean, default: 0}
next_request_at: {type: date, default: null}<-----
```

But I search everywhere and I don't know how I can modify my entity and create this column in my database. Someone know which is the command using to modify my entity in symfony 1.4 ??

Thank in advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity more than anything else, how come you're on Symfony 1.4? Is this a legacy project?

Comment: Yes It's a legacy project. And it's very difficult to me because I always use Symfony2.

Comment: Which ORM are you using - Propel or Doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Symfony 1.4 documentation](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/03?orm=Doctrine) you need to run these commands after modifying your schema file:

`php symfony doctrine:build --model`

`php symfony doctrine:build --sql`

`php symfony doctrine:insert-sql`

Before running these commands, please read to [this documentation page](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/03?orm=Doctrine) under the heading 'The ORM' just to make sure those commands are what you're looking for.

Doctrine entities can then be generated via this command

`php symfony doctrine:build --model`

Make sure to backup any existing work before doing this however, as it may overwrite any changes to existing classes.

Comment: Yes I modify my schema.yml and I want to modify my php class and create this column in my database in consequence. But I have a question. With this command there will be only the php class which are modify and my column will be created on my table in database ? Anything else ?

Comment: It's just I hope this command don't delete the data in my table and they don't create a file in double.

Comment: @arendelle I'd missed something there, my original answer only included ways to generate the sql structure. Apparently running this command `php symfony doctrine:build --model` will generate a php class in 'lib/model/' for you. If we're talking about existing classes, you are probably better off doing this manually or running that command ONLY after backing up your existing work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But after I use this command: "php symfony doctrine:build --model" i try to access my application and I got this error: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'i.label' in 'field list'

Comment: @arendelle it looks like somewhere the schema doesn't match up with the required SQL and classes. It's going to be a pain you'll have to manually comb through to find out where there was a mismatch. Or, you could revert back to where you started and manually add the columns into the db and the php classes.

Answer (score 0):

Before you create the new model classes (using the `doctrine:build` commands), you should create migration files.

For me, the process is usually:

- `./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`

  This should create a new file in `lib/migrations/doctrine` with commands to add any new columns.
- `./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`

  This will create or update the classes in `lib/{model,form,filter}/doctrine/base` to include the new columns.
- `./symfony doctrine:migrate`

  This actually runs the migration. Otherwise you'll get a SQL error because of the missing column. The migration clearly needs to be run on production as well; we have that as part of our deploy scripts to run every time.

If you've already built new classes, you'll need to add a few steps to the beginning of the above process:

- Temporarily comment out or revert the schema.yml change
- Run `./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`
- Make the schema.yml change again
- Go back to step 1, the `generate-migrations-diff` step above.